# Paging in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In my gridview I have 6 pages. When I go to page two and try to sort by descending on any of my columns I get sent back to page 1. Is there a way to stay at page two?

Comment: Why do you want to stay on page 2 when you sort and therefore the visible data changed completely?

Comment: page 2 is only as an example. it could be any page and the user wants to sort that page only?

Comment: "it could be any page and the user wants to sort that page only?"
Thats an important notice. It seems to be a contradiction and senseless to use paging and sorting but the user could only sort one page. Normally the whole datasource will be sorted and when the number of rows exceeds the PageSize(f.e. 10) the GridView creates Pages.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to assign the current `PageIndex` property of the GridView in your sorting method after the sort but before the DataBind.

Comment: Are you setting the **PageIndex** of your gridview in your **sorting method** as david suggests? Did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

In `PageIndexChanging` event, you need to set the page and rebind your data. For instance like following:

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    bindGridView();//a method that re/sets the datasource
}
```

Check [this article](http://programming.top54u.com/post/ASP-Net-2-0-Gridview-Paging-using-C-sharp.aspx).

Comment: Did you turn on the Paging? `AllowPaging="True"` and `PageSize="10"`. Also on page load I believe you have something like this `if (!IsPostBack) bindGridView();`

Comment: Did you turn on the Paging? Yes
AllowPaging="True" Yes 
and PageSize="10" Yes. 
Also on page load I believe you have something like this if (!IsPostBack) bindGridView(); I just tried that and it didnt work.

The problem is not paging and sorting. The problem is staying on page 2 for example after the sort is done??

Comment: @Jeff: For that matter, see Tim's response. One workaround could, save the currentPageNo in `ViewState`, as soon as the Sort is done, manually set the `GridView1.PageIndex` to currentPageNo and reset datasource.